ng drawerservice component called twice
ViewPurchaseOrder(item: any): void {
   this.drawerService.create({
      nzTitle: 'View Purchase Order',
      nzMaskClosable: true,
      nzWrapClassName: "full-drawer noSidebar",
      nzContent: NewPurchaseComponent,
      nzContentParams: { purchaseOrderData: item }
   });
 }

 ViewCreateOrder(item: any): void {

    this.drawerService.create({
      nzTitle: 'View Create Order',
      nzMaskClosable: true,
      nzWrapClassName: "md-drawer",
      nzContent: ViewProductCartComponent,
      nzContentParams: { createOrderData: item }
    });
  }

here i have two different methods drawer Services.
when i call ViewPurchaseOrder it will perfectly ok but when i call ViewCreateOrder then close drawer and if i call ViewPurchaseOrder  again
i dont know why it called ViewProductCartComponent that components?
I am unable to find out this, can anyone please sort this out?

Try storing the drawerRef and then calling close method on the previous drawer. Just a guess though.
drawerRef: any;
...


...
ViewPurchaseOrder(item: any): void {
   this.drawerRef?.close();
   this.drawerRef = this.drawerService.create({
      nzTitle: 'View Purchase Order',
      nzMaskClosable: true,
      nzWrapClassName: "full-drawer noSidebar",
      nzContent: NewPurchaseComponent,
      nzContentParams: { purchaseOrderData: item }
   });
 }

 ViewCreateOrder(item: any): void {
   this.drawerRef?.close();
   this.drawerRef = this.drawerService.create({
      nzTitle: 'View Create Order',
      nzMaskClosable: true,
      nzWrapClassName: "md-drawer",
      nzContent: ViewProductCartComponent,
      nzContentParams: { createOrderData: item }
    });
  }


not working i tried with these

@Shawn could you share a simple stackblitz where the issue happen for checking?
